# WSS Features and Data Storage

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

When developing complex features for SharePoint, what is the recommended method of data storage?  Should you constrain yourself to SP Lists and all the limitations that come with that, or use your own database, or create tables within the SP database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on how complex your data structure is. 
In my opinion:

- If the data being stored is extremely simple (like one text string or guid) you can use SPWeb.Properties.
- If it’s possible to do with lists without getting a headache. Use a list.
- If you need complex relations, use your own database.

Doing any direct access to the SharePoint database is unsorted and considered bad practice. Even if its very unlikely, an update to SharePoint could possibly remove your tables. So keep the content db clean and put your tables elsewhere.